# In MS-ACCESS How to create query to get list of store names that never sold ProductId with 13 or Milk 1 Litre?From table below:

Tags: database, ms-access

**Store table**
storeId  |   storeName
1        |   ElevenStore
3        |   SelkirkStore
4        |   CalgaryStore
5        |   BordenStore
**Product table**
Product ID |    Product Name
1          |      Chai
2          |     Black tea
3          |      maple syrup
13  |   milk 1 litre
**Sales table**
storeId |   productId
1       |    1
1       |    2
1       |    3
1       |    1
3       |    13
3       |    12
4       |    3
4       |   1
5       |    13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Store.*
FROM Store
WHERE storeID NOT IN(SELECT storeID FROM Sales WHERE productID=13);
```

If you want all products not sold by each store, consider:

```
SELECT StoreProduct.*
FROM Sales RIGHT JOIN (SELECT Store.storeId, Store.storeName, Product.ProductID, Product.ProductName
FROM Store, Product) AS StoreProduct ON (Sales.productID = StoreProduct.ProductID) AND (Sales.[storeID] = StoreProduct.[storeId])
WHERE (((Sales.productID) Is Null))
ORDER BY StoreProduct.storeID, StoreProduct.productID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was going mad. 
Can you Please suggest where I can find explanation for this? Still little bit confused.

Comment: I think the first query is rather self-explanatory. The second uses a Cartesian query (the nested SELECT statement). Cartesian query does not have JOIN clause which means records of each table associate with each record of other table to generate a dataset of possible store/product pairs. Then that query is joined to store table to perform a 'Find Unmatched' query.